# NaCl code example of screen recording

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I am looking for a sample code that makes a video out of a desktop screen recording, I already managed to get the recording ready with all the settings ready.

I am looking for a simple code to turn the stream to a video if you have an example I would love to see.

I do not have any experience in this field, so I am not sure how to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`chrome.desktopCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture), Desktop Capture API that can be used to capture content of screen, individual windows or tabs.

Take note that DesktopCapture API needs permission. As we get access to this API.

**manifest.json:**

```
"permissions": [
"desktopCapture",
"https://localhost:8000/*"
]
```

Gets access to the stream, and sends a message containing the chromeMediaSourceId (streamID)

```
function requestScreenSharing(port, msg) {
desktopMediaRequestId =
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(data_sources, port.sender.tab,
function (streamId) {
msg.type = 'SS_DIALOG_SUCCESS';
msg.streamId = streamId;
port.postMessage(msg);
});
}

if (event.data.type && (event.data.type === 'SS_DIALOG_SUCCESS')) {
startScreenStreamFrom(event.data.streamId);
}

function startScreenStreamFrom(streamId) {
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
video: {
mandatory: {
chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
// ...
}
}
},
// successCallback
function(screenStream) {
videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(screenStream);
videoElement.play();
}
```

For more information regarding Chrome's desktopCapture, please follow the link: https://github.com/wpp/ScreenStream

Comment: I tried this case, the performance was horrible and the video size was huge. I am puzzled!!!